# to use CRYPT_BLOWFISH on php 5.2 that doesn't support it

Tags: php, blowfish, crypt, php-5.2

I am running my page on PHP 5.2 that does not support `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` but `CRYPT_MD5`, and have heard that the blowfish is much more safer than md5.

Since I am not the supervisor thing, I can not upgrade PHP to a version that supports it.

Is there any hack for using `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` on PHP 5.2?

and,

```
$hash_key = crypt($something, '$2a$anySalt');
```

is pasting '$2a$' at the very first side correct?

quite confused.

P.s. If I use [`crypt()`](http://php.net/crypt) with `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`, will bcrypt work well in the `crypt()` function?

Comment: The simple answer is to get a host that uses maintained versions of PHP. 5.2 is End-Of-Life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [PHPASS](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) which has fallbacks to support systems that don't support CRYPT_BLOWFISH. Otherwise you can't really use bcrypt from PHP that I know of.

Comment: It should be noted that PHPass, in its portable modem, the mode that works with 5.2, will fall back to salted md5 hashes with multiple iterations. Of course, this was answered several years ago, but at this point md5 is no longer secure, anyone on PHP 5.2 needs to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, if you aren't using PHP 5.6 or newer (preferably PHP 7), you really should upgrade! The new http://php.net/password_hash method is far superior.