# encryption using PHP crypt

Tags: php

I’m having a problem in encryption using PHP crypt

Following is my code :

```
echo $ret = crypt('Dave@123','$2y$10$XLLl50bLyTWfjcvCAxwGRu/px2Q.LXN0fHpD1KN2CQCMx/tpL1V62');
```

1) When using crypt in PHP Version 5.4.22
   It results:

```
 $2y$10$XLLl50bLyTWfjcvCAxwGRu/px2Q.LXN0fHpD1KN2CQCMx/tpL1V62
```

2) When used with PHP Version 5.2.17 it results

```
 $25nFTQHtfjVg
```

I want the same result as 1.

Comment: Are you aware that your first result from 1) shows the second input to the crypt function? I wouldn't want to get my input as output back.

Comment: @Samuel You are aware that this is intended behaviour?

Comment: PHP 5.2 is end of live. You actually don't want that. -- -1: Only wanting sth. does not qualify as a programming question. Edit: Shame on you upvoters (:)): Even more votes than the duplicate that exists for months and has answers (!).

Comment: possible duplicate of [to use CRYPT\_BLOWFISH on php 5.2 that doesn't support it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637445/to-use-crypt-blowfish-on-php-5-2-that-doesnt-support-it)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `2y` blowfish prefix. It was introduced after a security issue in PHP 5.3.7 and so PHP 5.2 does not know about it, sees an invalid `$salt` and generates an invalid hash.

The equivalent in PHP 5.2 is `2a`, but it might be affected by the mentioned security issue (I did not check).

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/crypt). I came to know that they introduced **Update**  $2y$ Blowfish modes on 5.3.7. So in PHP 5.2.17 you may get DES. The type of hashing is decided from the salt you provides.